# How to insert a $_POST array into a MySQL table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert the following $_POST array into a MySQL table:

```
Array (
    [name] => asd
    [number] => 2
    [date_of_birth] => 2008-06-17
    [address] => asd
    [email] => asd@gmail.com
    [gender] => male
    [salary] => 22212
    [date_of_join] => 2015-04-08
    [degree_of_learning] => bechelore degree
)
```

I tried using this code and I get no errors but the array is not inserted into my table:

```
<?php
    include('db.php');

    $columns = implode(", ",array_keys($_POST));
    $escaped_values = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_values($_POST));
    $values  = implode("', '", $escaped_values);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `trainers`($columns) VALUES ('$values');";
    echo $sql;
    mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

Here is the output of `echo $sql`:

```
INSERT INTO `trainers`(name, number, date_of_birth, address, email,
gender, salary, date_of_join, degree_of_learning) VALUES ('asd', '2',
'2008-06-17', 'asd', 'asd@gmail.com', 'male', '22212', '2015-04-08',
'bechelore degree ');
```

I tried inserting that directly on the server and it worked, but it does not work in my PHP code.

My table definition is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trainers (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    number varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    date_of_birth date NOT NULL,
    address varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    gender varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    salary int(11) NOT NULL,
    date_of_join date NOT NULL,
    degree_of_learning varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)  ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2;
```

Comment: Taking all POST vars and inserting them blindly into a database could be considered dangerous. Have you tried using prepared statements instead?

Comment: I get no errors
but it does not inserted into my table

Comment: Array ( [name] => asd [number] => 2 [date_of_birth] => 2008-06-17 [address] => asd [email] => asd@gmail.com [gender] => male [salary] => 22212 [date_of_join] => 2015-04-08 [degree_of_learning] => bechelore degree )

this my $_POST array

Comment: could you send your table structure?

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `trainers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `number` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date_of_birth` date NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `salary` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_of_join` date NOT NULL,
  `degree_of_learning` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

Comment: `salary` column is probably your problem, since it is an INT and you are inserting all values as strings.

Comment: @dan08 MySQL will just convert the string to int automatically.

Comment: You should check the result of mysql_query-- false indicates a failure in which case you should check mysql_error() to see why it failed. Also mysql_ is deprecated and mysqli or PDO is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

You need a link in order to send your query. You also must escape from your SQL string as well so you can call your php variables. This may not fully fix your problem, but this should definitely get you on the right track.

```
<?php
  include('db.php');//is your db.php creating a link to the database?
  /*I would use something along these lines.

  $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "dbuser", "dbpassword", "dbname");

  if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die ("There was an error connecting to the database");
  } */

  $columns = implode(",",array_keys($_POST));
    $values  = implode("','", array_values($_POST));
    $query = "INSERT INTO `Table Name`(".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $columns).") VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $values)."')";//insert your table name here
    echo $query; 
    mysqli_query($link, $query);//added the $link here
```

Comment: Your arguments are backwards for mysql_query, but it will use the last opened connection if unspecified in any event so probably not the issue.

Answer (score -3):

Change this line

```
 $values  = implode("', '", $escaped_values);
```

to

```
$values  = implode("','", $escaped_values);
```